Get String Length - How It Works
I not asking about a problem, only about how it works.
@echo off

Set str=You
Call :$len str len
set len

Set str=I You
Call :$len str len
set len

Set str=I and You
Call :$len str len
set len

Set str=I, You and Them
Call :$len str len
set len

pause& exit

:$len
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set s=#!%~1!
set c=0
set nums=32 16 8 4 2 1
for %%N in (%nums%) do if not "!s:~%%N,1!"=="" set /a c+=%%N& set s=!s:~%%N!
(endlocal & set %~2=%c%)& exit /b

Output:
len=3
len=5
len=9
len=15

I still can't understand how it works.
How can the script get len value when it is not in the nums list ?
3,5,9,15 value not in set nums=32 16 8 4 2 1 for %%N in (%nums%)
Can anyone explain the logic ?
Source: How-to: Get the length of a String - strlen.cmd

I will compare with the script below that I can understand the logic.
the result is the same
rem same as the script above
:$len
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set s=#!%~1!
set c=0
for /L %%N in (0 1 25) do if not "!s:~%%N,1!"=="" set c=%%N
(endlocal & set %~2=%c%)& exit /b

I Understood because len value 3,5,9,15 obtained from for /L %%N in (0 1 25)

How can the script get len value when it is not in the nums list?
len is passed into the function when it is called using:
Call :$len str len

The functions sets it using this code snippet:
set %~2=%c%

where %~2 is len and %c% is the calculated length.

I've edited the question which may have been ambiguous. because my English is not good

What I mean is  len value 3,5,9,15 not in set nums=32 16 8 4 2 1

That's the calculated length of your strings?

I'm really not understanding where you are stuck with your understanding?

for example len value 3 is from ? Is it from 3 * 1 ?.  or 2 + 1 or else

if not "!s:~%%N,1!"=="" set c=%%N in a loop looks for the end of the string.

Thanks for your time, Sir.

@echo off

set "_var=My len = 59 | It can be summarized in a single for /f loop:"

for /f usebackq %%G in =;(` 
     %ComSpec% /u /c set /p "=%_var:"= %"^<nul^|find /v /c "" 
   `);= do set "_len=%%~G"

echo/%_len%  



Output:

59


The current method in use is using extensive and complicated code compared to another option that uses a single for /f loop with redirection counting characters.
PS.: I've been using this loop for many years, more than 20 and I don't remember the source, probably at dostips.com

Thanks for share other method. I think this method slower if called repeatedly. I have tested.  total "33" secons to get length 3,5,9,15 above. Use script from ss64.com only need 3 secons

By the way, I rarely find a format like this %%G in =;(. Generally%%G in (. What's its function ? =;

Nice idea, get time/running. and this is my "style" =;(   );= and %:^) for :label

Nice. You make a unique style.
